# /bin and /usr/bin both being mounted to same location in Git Bash

Tags: windows, git-bash

Git Bash for Windows (v 4.4.19) mounts "`C:/Program Files/Git`" as "`/`" and mounts  "`C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin`" as "`/bin`"

This means that `/usr/bin` and `/bin` are being mounted to the same exact underlying Windows folder.  This creates a problem because `bash` and `git` are not recognized unless I add `/c/Program Files/git/cmd` directly to my PATH.

Is there a config file to change this?  Why is the same folder being mounted twice?

Comment: I would like to point out that so far no one has answered this question.

Comment: Please used `git --version` instead of `bash --version` to describe the version number of git-bash you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Having `/bin` linked to `/usr/bin` is something that is now also being done on a number of linux and unix distributions. You can read the rational for that here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/

Comment: I agree that this is probably what they are attempting to do (cygwin does something similar, but in the opposite direction), however, unless $GITPATH/bin (`/c/Program Files/Git/bin` on my system) is explicitly added to the path, `git` and `bash` are not actually available.  To me, this indicates that the implementation on Mingw64 is broken, as /usr/bin and /bin are not properly unified.  It still doesn't answer the questions of is it possible to change this behavior, or is there documentation from the Mingw64/git for windows, projects explaining why this decision was made.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, before calling bash, to have your `%PATH%` (Windows CMD PATH) set to:

```
set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

You will then see, in a bash, session that:

- `/usr/bin` is set to the full content of `%G%\usr\bin` and `%G%\mingw64\bin`
- `/bin` is only displays `%G%\bin` plus [builtin commands only](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html)

That is:

```
vonc@vonc:/$ ls /usr/bin|wc -l
1160
vonc@vonc:/$ ls /bin|wc -l
149
```

That started with the [support of MingW2 in 2015](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/42), and later the [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) project.

Yet, `/bin` is mounted to `%G%\usr\bin`.

> Is there a config file to change this?

Yes: `/etc/mtab`

```
$ cat /etc/mtab
D:/prgs/git/latest / ntfs binary,noacl,auto 1 1
D:/prgs/git/latest/usr/bin /bin ntfs binary,noacl,auto 1 1
C:/Users/vonc/AppData/Local/Temp /tmp ntfs binary,noacl,posix=0,usertemp 1 1
```

So `/bin` is only mounted once: to .

> Why is the same folder being mounted twice?

Since `/` is mounted to `%G%`, `/usr/bin` is also a reference (not a mount) to `%G%\usr\bin`.

Git 2.5.2.2 (Sept 2015) illustrates this with [issue 405](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/405) and [commit bf980fd](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/commit/bf980fd1623eee9f1866aeaef328c3522a3d8798). (see also [PR 79](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/79)).

Comment: This does not appear to work after tackling this from multiple directions.  I tried adding to the user's path via the Environment Variables dialog in the Control Panel.  I tried adding it via the AutoStart cmd file, and I have tried setting manually from the cmd.  I can confirm that the %PATH% variable is correct, but the /bin directory is still mounted to the C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin path (as shown in /proc/mounts). I seem to remember a config file from a while back, but it has been a long time.  I would also expect bash to pick up the PATH regardless of how it is opened.

Comment: @drz Agreed. I have edited the answer. And added the config file.

Comment: I looked at the /etc/mtab file when I first started trying to figure this out.  It is symlinked to /proc/mounts which is in turn linked to /proc/self/mounts.  /proc/self is linked to a numbered directory under /proc, which running ps reveals is a PID for a bash instance.  Each new bash instance gets a new PID and thus a new folder under /proc.  cat against the mount points does show what is mounted, but the file is not editable.  Since stat always shows a create time equal to now, and a size of 0, and chmod doesn't work on this file, I have to assume it is virtually created by bash.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself with Conda on Windows. I believe that the answer is given in [the Cygwin mount table docs](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table). By default, Cygwin will automatically mount `{cygwin-prefix}\bin` to `/usr/bin`. But this behavior can be overridden if there's an entry in your `/etc/fstab` that mounts *something else* to `/usr/bin`. [This code on GitHub](https://github.com/cygwin/cygwin/blob/1e428bee1c5ef7c76ba4e46e6693b913edc9bbf3/winsup/cygwin/mount.cc#L508-L512) looks like the implementation of that logic.

Now the astute reader will note that this is backwards! In the original question, and my experience with Conda, `{cygwin-prefix}\usr\bin` is mounted to `/bin`. That's because MSYS2, which uses a fork of Cygwin for its runtime, [switches the prefixing pattern](https://github.com/msys2/msys2-runtime/blob/msys2-3_3_6-release/winsup/cygwin/mount.cc#L500-L508).

Either way, if you can edit your `/etc/fstab`, you can avoid the issue. For my Mambaforge install in an IE Edge Windows 10 VM, the following line adds a mount that is redundant, but prevents the shadowing:

```
C:/Users/IEUser/mambaforge/Library/bin /bin whatever binary,posix=0,noacl,user 0 0
```

Adding `/usr` in the first two items would be appropriate for a stock Cygwin setup, I think.

**PS:** In Conda installs, at least, I should note that while this solution is technically correct I have found it not to work reliably, because package updates will overwrite your `/etc/fstab` file. Both the `git` and `m2-filesystem` packages provide (slightly different, sigh) versions of the file. I haven't tried it, but it's possible that a user-specific file in `/etc/fstab.d`, as mentioned by the Cygwin docs linked above, might provide a way to avoid this issue. But I just futz with my $PATH.